# Bootstrap - remove background from navbar link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work on coding a website using the Bootstrap development kit. I've set up the navigation bar with a couple of links but I'm having some trouble with some custom links I've added. I added CSS to the bootstrap.min.css file titled 'navbar-social', which will be used to house social media icons for the navigation bar.

I added the images just fine and they display great. The problem I'm having is when I add a link to them they go out of line and hovering over them gives them a background box which I do not want.

I've attached some screenshots and the code used, I cannot for the life of me work out where the background box is coming from, because checking the a styles doesn't seem to have anything there. I'm new to CSS so I apologise if I'm missing something obvious.

None linked: http://prntscr.com/2ob9mj

LinkedIn not linked, rest linked: http://prntscr.com/2ob2b2

CSS code added to bootstrap.min.css. Rest is as it comes:

```
.navbar-social{
float:right !important;
padding:5px;
font-size:18px;
line-height:37px;
height:20px
}
```

HTML: (a href removed in this case)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
             <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="">REMOVED</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Programming <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C++</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Actionscript 3.0</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li class="navbar-social"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" /></li>
                    <li class="navbar-social"><img src="images/github.png" alt="GitHub" /></li>
                    <li class="navbar-social"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></li>
                    <li class="navbar-social"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Bootstrap adds styles to `<a>` tags in the navbar. Use firebug or Chrome's Dev Tools to see what's being applied and then overwrite them within your custom CSS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bootstrap adds styling to the child `a` elements. You could simply overwrite it using the following:

[**WORKING EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndeQ4/)

```
.nav .navbar-social > a {
    padding:0;
}
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```